# Using bulk DB operations with auto-increment PK

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Entity A has a table TA (ID int PK autoinc, f1, f2, f3).

Using JPA over Hibernate, we save a record to A. The ID field is marked as the Key. We have set the batch size to 100 hoping that after 100 records are saved to the repository, physical INSERTs will be invoked. However, JPA/Hibernate apparently INSERTs each record as soon as the persist is called, possibly because it has to set the value of the key field which it can only get from the DB.

This means when we have a PK which is autoincrement, it will not be possible to perform the DB operations in a batch? Am I missing some annotation/configuration that can let me still perform the inserts in a batch?

I do not need the entity to be managed after inserting the records.

Thanks,

Yash

Answer (score 0):

It would be probably good if you would post what Database engine you are using. Every DB implementation has kind of its own batch optimisation for inserts. JPA is not really up to date on all of those.

I think if you go for performance optimising you should actually first review the database docs of the engine/version you run and what exactly is supported in it. And then look in the JPA implementation you are using (like OpenJPA or Hibernate?) if they support this syntax.

I tried using batch parameters for JPA various times, the issue is that this batch update is still very slow. Usually DB vendor provides multiple insert syntax alternatives other then supported by JPA. JPA's batch update simply means that all inserts are executed in a single transaction. But it does not use DB vendor specific optimised SQL.

Example: MSSQL supports multiple tupples per insert statement (up to 1000 I think).

so instead of

```
INSERT INTO [my.[dbo].[entity]
       ([col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES ('val1a','val2a','val3a');
INSERT INTO [my.[dbo].[entity]
       ([col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES ('val1b','val2b','val3b');
```

You can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO [my.[dbo].[entity]
       ([col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES ('val1a','val2a','val3a')
      ,('val1b','val2b','val3b');
```

The latter statement is a lot faster then executing the first two inserts. Also if you would bundle the first two in a single transaction via JPA's "batch update"

But the latter syntax is not supported by most of the JPA implementations, so I had to write a native query to get there. And there are more performance optimised ways of imports/inserts/updates for each DB vendor. You won't find those in JPA implementations.

So instead of trying to make a JPA annotation/JPQL query work I would rather first decide on what performance optimisation you want to achieve and then write a native sql query and execute it via JPA. Every JPA implementation has methods for executing native queries.